# How to append an array (hardcoded way) to a json array with append function

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I work on json path and I study the differents functions of this query language.
I tried to use the 'append' function to see how far we can go with it and here's my case :

```json
{
    "book": [{
            "category": "reference"
        }, {
            "category": "fiction"
        }
    ],
    "rndarr": ["foo", 10]
}
```

Here's my goal : I want to retrieve all book array and add to this array another array, so I tried this : `$.book.append(["foo",10])` and it returned me this :

```json
[
    {
        "category": "reference"
    },
    {
        "category": "fiction"
    },
    "foo"
]
```

As you can see the `10` completly disappear, and here's another weird behavior : when I run this : `$.book.append([10])` it returns this :

```json
[
    {
        "category": "reference"
    },
    {
        "category": "fiction"
    },
    "10]"
]
```

To makes things clear my expected output should normally be this (for the first problem) :

```json
[
    {
        "category": "reference"
    },
    {
        "category": "fiction"
    },
    ["foo", 10]
]
```

After all of this I tried to make a trick. I tried to call an array that already exist `rndarr` and it works : `$.book.append($.rndarr)` this return the expected output

```json
[
    {
        "category": "reference"
    },
    {
        "category": "fiction"
    },
    [
        "foo",
        10
    ]
]
```

So my question is : Is it possible to write in an hard-coded way a jsonpath that use append function with an array ?

Comment: just a guess `$.book.append("['foo' ,10]")`

Comment: @j.holetzeck no it doesn't work it just add a string `['foo' ,10]`